# Performing wildcard search using the json_contains function in mysql 5.7 and above

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, json

I have some nested json data that i get using the `json_object()` function. Now I need to to check whether a certain value exists for a particular key which I am using as follows in my query:-

```
select json_object(..) from tblxyz 
  where json_contains(columnname, '{"MyName" : "FirstName LastName"}')
```

The problem with this approach is that I require the entire string "FirstName LastName" to find this row in the actual result.
Now I need to perform a wild card search. That is:-

```
select json_object(..) from tblxyz 
  where json_contains(columnname, '{"MyName" : "FirstName"}')
```

should also return this entry to me in the final result. Can someone please suggest any workaround?

Answer (score 6):

You can use JSON_SEARCH with wildcards:

```
SET @j = '{"MyName": "FirstName LastName"}';
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(@j, 'all', 'FirstName%', NULL, '$.MyName');
```

Will return the path: `"$.MyName"`

If you want to filter by this, use an alias and check it in a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(`json_col`, 'all', 'FirstName%', NULL, '$.MyName') as `search`
FROM `users`
HAVING `search` IS NOT NULL;
```

or.. in a `WHERE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(`json_col`, 'all', 'FirstName%', NULL, '$.MyName') IS NOT NULL;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html

Comment: Can that use an `INDEX`?  Or must it read every row?

Comment: @RickJames You can't INDEX the JSON column itself, but you can create virtual columns to extract scalar values from that JSON and INDEX on those

Comment: There are some advantages with such an approach, but it is roughly equivalent to making it an explicit column with an explicit index.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you are really expecting too much from JSON in a database.

Any JSON "fields" that need to be searched/sorted/joined/etc in a relational database manner should be pulled out (or at least copied out) into their own column(s).

Comment: This is entirely possible, see my posted solution.